# Finding differences in two excel sheets

Tags: excel, compare

I have two sheets in excel that each have three columns: Id, Description1, Description2.

[Sheets Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UvgvF.png)

Both sheets will have the same ID's in the first column, however some of them have different descriptions.

I'm trying to compare both and remove the rows that are completely identical. Thus, leaving only the rows with differences left. And preferably place those differences in a new sheet.

I'm unfamiliar with the excel syntax, could someone please give me an idea of how to accomplish this?

Thanks

Comment: As your are not so familiar with excel in advance, I would suggest you to follow these steps. 1. Create a new sheet. 2. Copy data form both sheet to new sheet. 3. Try remove duplicate method from `DATA` tab of excel ribbon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used the remove duplicate function within excel as suggested by Harun23HR.